# Video encoding Help

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, streaming-flv-video

I'm doing one research on video encoding tools for flv.

I tested flvtool2 and Yamddi, but I'm losing lots of quality of video.

Does anyone recommend any other tool or algorithm to keep the maximum quality of the movie in flv?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MPEG4 (H.264/AAC) instead.

[How to best convert Flash compatible mp4 files with FFMPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453352/how-to-best-convert-flash-compatible-mp4-files-with-ffmpeg)